# Overlap multiple div over div underneath

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have actually two questions about the following layout.

[image]

If I see this layout, I see 2 main div. The first div with the 3 columns in it has a white background. And the second div with a blue background.

The first div overlaps the div underneath. But also the "content" of the second div has to break out of that div. As you see, the big blue circle breaks out.

This is already what I have:

```
    <style>
    .block--33 {
        flex-basis: calc(33% - 1rem);
        margin-right: 1rem;
    }

    .block--33:nth-child(3) {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .background--blue {
        background: darkblue;
    }

    .digital-dealer {
        margin-bottom: 5rem;
    }

    </style>
    <section class="digital-dealer">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="block block--33">

            <h2>Go</h2>

            </div>
            <div class="block block--33">

            <h2>Pro</h2>

            </div>
            <div class="block block--33">

            <h2>Expert</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="background--blue">

    </section>
```

Comment: What are the questions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am understanding your question correctly, but I think you will just need to control this with absolute positioning and z-index in your CSS.  You can also achieve this layout with relative positioning, but it would require some negative values and is not considered a good practice.

You might need to clarify the specifics of the question to get an accurate answer.  Basically, the `digital-dealer` class will have a higher z-index than the `background--blue` div.

```
.block--33 {
    flex-basis: calc(33% - 1rem);
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.block--33:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.background--blue {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%
    background: darkblue;
    z-index:50;
}

.digital-dealer {
    position:absolute;
    top:10%
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Here are some additional resources for your questions.

Absolute Positioning:  https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_position.asp

Z-Index: 
https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_pos_z-index.asp